# SQLSafe Backup Restore Scripts Automation

Tags: t-sql

Anyone has written script to automate the restoration process when databases are backed up via SQLSafe? My backups run in this format:

SQLSafe Backup (full - weekly)
SQLSafe Backup (diffs - daily)
SQLSafe Backup (log - every 15 minutes).

I wanted to find out of anyone has restore script automation already written for this.

Thanks in advance.

-Subhash

Answer (score 0):

A quick search found this: ["Auto generate SQL Server restore script from backup files in a directory"](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1584). You'd use this if you have restore files ready to use

You can also build your own if you query [sys.backup_files](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/tsql3/using-msdb-backup-tables.aspx) etc at the time of backup.